# Problem with example in tcolorbox package

Tags: tcolorbox

When I try to run this simple example from the manual:

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\tcbset{frame style={top color=red!20!white,
                     bottom color=red!20!white!75!black},
        fonttitle=\bfseries,coltitle=black}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,title=My title,interior hidden]
This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\tcblower
This is the lower part.
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

I get a strange error:

---

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tcb/frame style', to which you
 passed 'top color=red!20!white, bottom color=red!20!white!75!black', and I am
going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                             

l.82         fonttitle=\bfseries,coltitle=black}

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have read on Stack Exchange and other forums that the problem is an outdated version of `tcolorbox`, but I am running the latest version of both `tcolorbox` and of `PGF`, here the inserts from the log file:

```
Package: tcolorbox 2015/03/16 version 3.50 text color boxes

Package: pgf 2013/12/18 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.14)
```

Anyone can shed some light on the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to load the appropriate library for `frame style` to work out. Here it is `skins`. If in doubt, you may add `most` or `many` as the options to `tcolorbox`

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
%\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\tcbset{frame style={top color=red!20!white,
                     bottom color=red!20!white!75!black},
        fonttitle=\bfseries,coltitle=black}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,title=My title,interior hidden]
This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\tcblower
This is the lower part.
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Right on! Very cryptic message on part of the package that should know the skin library is not loaded! Thanks very much.

Comment: @PauloNey Thanks for the up vote. :-)